# Control output in mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation

I'm producing a set of coordinates for every iteration in a simulation and saving it into a txt file in the following way:

```
Table[write[myfile,CoorSet[data,i]],{i,1,1000}]
```

In CoorSet there is a lenghty calculation that produces the coordinates, it works well, however in same cases there is a double output and some cases there is non.

So the output looks as follows:

```
{-1,1}
{-1,2}
{0,3}
{{1,-1},{20,12}}
{2,4}
0.01*Round[{}+{-1,-1}] (* the line of calculation*)
```

How do I replace the written lines output with {0,0} whenever there is the written line.

and whenever there is a double set of coordinates, how can the one that is further away by distance from its neighbors be suppressed such that the table that I will get will be:

```
{-1,1}
{-1,2}
{0,3}
{1,-1}
{2,4}
{0,0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let,s say this is your input

> list = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {{1, -1}, {20, 12}}, {2, 4}, 
>                "0.01*Round[{}+{-1,-1}]"}

First replace the `String`

```
list = list /. x__ /; StringQ[x] -> {0, 0}

Join[{list[[1]]},
 Table[s = list[[i]];
  If[Length[Flatten@s] > 2,
  d = Min[{Norm[s[[#]] - list[[i - 1]]], 
    Norm[s[[#]] - list[[i + 1]]]}] & /@ Range[Length[s]];
  d1 = Join[s // Transpose, {d}] // Transpose;
  Sort[d1, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &][[1, 1 ;; 2]],
  s],
{i, 2, Length[list] - 1}],
{list[[-1]]}]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, -1}, {2, 4}, {0, 0}}